# Sameness property for graphs

Tags: graph-theory, notation, asymptotics

I consider graphs with edge density $\frac{1}{2}$ and $d$-regularity, where $d=(1+o(1))\frac{n}{2}$. Edge density $\frac{1}{2}$ means, that the the half of all possible edges exists.
Due to an article it can be followed that
\begin{equation} \label{1}
s(v,w)=(1+o(1))\frac{n}{2},
\end{equation}
where $s(v,w):=|\{u \in V: a(v,u)=a(w,u)\}|$ is the number of all edges $u$, which are either adjacent to both $v$ or $w$ or are non-adjacent to both $v$ and $w$. 
I cannot find a formal proof for it. Can someone help me?

Comment: This seems wrong. Try it on a disjoint union of two cliques of size $n/2$.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I read this equation in the following paper: http://m.mathnet.or.kr/mathnet/kms_tex/100264.pdf, p.4.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Do you know why this is true: $s(v,w)=2|N(v) \cap N(w)|+n-2d$, where $N$ is the neighbourhood. I would be very thankful for any help

Comment: I'm sure you can figure this out on your own. Use a Venn diagram.